# Array of children passed as prop in react

Tags: reactjs

When an array of children are passed as prop and looped over to render in parent component, react is complaining about missing unique key identifier on array iteration.

What is the correct way to overcome the warning?

Can I pass key along with children under prop.

If I want to set key to children while rendering in parent, it is complaining child's key prop is read only.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Would be easier if you shared some code.**

You shouldn't need to iterate the children to render then, unless you are augmenting them in some way.

```
class MyComponent extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {this.props.children}
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

If you must, can you wrap them in a `div` and apply the key to that instead?

```
class MyComponent extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {this.props.children.map((child, index) => (<div key={index}>{child}</div>))}
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

I haven't tried this but you might be able to clone the element and change the key

```
class MyComponent extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {this.props.children.map((child, index) => {React.cloneElement(child, {key: index})})}
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: I have the first solution in place now and key is included within prop itself. For some reason it does not feel right to me. Ex:
<Component
      elements={[<li key="0">1</li>,
      <li key="1">2</li>,
      <li key="2">3</li>>]}
 />

Comment: Why pass them as a prop when you can just nest them? i.e. `<Component><li>1</li><li>2</li><li>3</li></Component>` (assuming `Component` creates the `<ul>` tag).

Comment: I cannot nest children that way in this scenario. They will be passed as an array to parent and then parents displays them accordingly.

Comment: You need to edit your question with some more code if you want better help.  Show the parent component and a component that uses it.

Comment: But the short answer is if you are rendering a list, [you _must_ provide the keys when creating the elements](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/lists-and-keys.html).  You might be able to get around it by [cloning the elements](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-api.html#cloneelement) before rendering.